I've dismissed all spirits in adventure, is this a soft-lock?
So, I dismissed all spirits in adventure. Now I'm realising the mistake since there are map obstacles that I could once traverse (like the big rocks) but I've now released the spirits that could get rid of these things.
What do I do now? Do I need to sit on the spirit board and wait for a time when those spirits are there, then defeat them?
Feels like I've soft locked myself until I can get those spirits back.

Copying answers from your Reddit Crosspost:

[–]almightyFaceplant 3 points 3 months ago
You're not screwed, the good news is you can use any Spirits you earn from other modes in World of Light. And the game will try to present you with things that you haven't unlocked yet, so just keep an eye on the Spirit Board and Shop.
It also wouldn't hurt your chances if you started collecting things you don't have collected yet, to make it more likely that the Spirits necessary for progression will be offered instead.
Also, the majority of obstacles can be solved with a couple different Spirits. (Basically anyone who's bomb-themed can blow up rocks, for example.)


[–]confidentlystranded 4 points 3 months ago
Some of them you can get from the Smash Ultimate in-game shop for those coins you get from playing games that you probably forgot you were earning


[–]Mangledfox1987 6 points 3 months ago
So you would either need for those spirits to appear on the board, or start a new adventure mode on a different save file

